# Convert datetime.datetime from UTC to CEST one hour to less

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, python-dateutil

If I run the following code I convert the datetime.datetime from utc to cest, but it does not work right. Correct would be if it would change from 21:29 to 23:29 because the time difference is 2 hours

```
from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = tz.gettz('CEST')

created_at
Out[302]: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 21, 29, 34)

utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
Out[303]: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 21, 29, 34, tzinfo=tzwin('UTC'))

utc.astimezone(to_zone)
Out[304]: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 22, 29, 34, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600), 'Mitteleuropäische Zeit'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correct localization, provide a [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), e.g.

```
to_zone = tz.gettz('Europe/Berlin')
```

Bringing up @GiacomoCatenazzi's comment, note that the IANA time zone (here: Europe/Berlin) relates to a geographical region whilst the associated "abbreviations" (here: CET/CEST) relate to offsets from UTC during certain periods of the year. Multiple geographical time zones *can* share the same offset to UTC, e.g. Europe/Berlin and Europe/Paris even change between CET and CEST [simultaneously in 2020](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-dst-end-2020.html).

***But:*** the other way round, it's 1) ambiguous or 2) even invalid:

1. multiple geographical regions can have the CEST UTC offset
   during certain times
2. for example there is no CEST on 2020-01-01 (although countries somewhere else in the world might have UTC+2 at that time...)

Comment: Or better: CEST has the same timezone as CET (Central European Time Zone). The difference is time offset (+1:00 and +2:00). This confuses many people, because we tend to merge both concepts. One is a geographic zone, the other is a time offset compared to UTC. "30 January 2020" is not summer in Europe.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: very good point, tried to add it to the answer.